# How do I stop Ubuntu One from telling me its file service will be shutting down two weeks ago?

Tags: 12.04, ubuntu-one, notification

I have Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.

Starting a few weeks ago, every time I boot a message would pop up in the notification area and say that Ubuntu One's file services will be shutting down June 1st, 2014.

This makes no sense because:

- I've never used Ubuntu One's file services. In fact, I uninstalled Ubuntu One over a year ago.
- It's good that the service will be shutting down on June 1st, but it's June 16th now.
- These messages didn't start until after June 1st anyways.

How do I make this message stop?

Comment: looks like you have not removed U1 properly. try `dpkg -l` and check if all packages related to U1 have been removed.

Comment: @RegisteredUser There were about a dozen, mostly `ubuntuone-client` and related. I removed them and the message finally stopped! I originally removed Ubuntu One from the software center, but I guess it didn't get everything. Thanks!!

Comment: would you write an answer and accept it so that the question does not go in the unanswered list?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following *Registered User*'s advice from the comments, I checked to make sure there were no Ubuntu One related packages left on the system:

```
dpkg -l | grep ubuntuone
```

I found a handful (I had originally removed Ubuntu One through the software center but I guess it didn't get everything). In my case:

- python-ubuntuone-client
- python-ubuntuone-control-panel
- python-ubuntuone-storageprotocol
- ubuntuone-client
- ubuntuone-client-gnome
- ubuntuone-control-panel
- ubuntuone-couch

I removed these packages, rebooted to test, and the message was finally gone.

It's still weird to me that the message didn't start until *after* June 1st but, the world may never know.